# Variable xaxis gap matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

so I'm trying to do spacing based on the value when doing a graph matplot lib
for example with these values:

```
Xaxis = [1, 2, 5]
Yaxis = [1, 2, 3]

ax.plot(Xaxis, Yaxis)
```

[Poor quality graph made in MSPaint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtiIX.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use need to use `plt.xticks(Xaxis)`:

```
Xaxis = [1, 2, 5]
Yaxis = [1, 2, 3]

plt.plot(Xaxis, Yaxis)
plt.xticks(Xaxis) # <--- here
```

---

[image]